# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/web/embedded/undertow/UndertowDeploymentInfoCustomizer

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I'm trying to do a simple key cloak configuration with spring boot and when i try to run the application i'm getting the following exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/web/embedded/undertow/UndertowDeploymentInfoCustomizer
```

The example which i referred from http://www.andrew-programming.com/2019/05/26/integrate-spring-security-and-keycloak/
and below is my `pom.xml`

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Here i'm using keycloak 10.0.1 version

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the version from:

```
<version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
```

to:

```
<version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
```